# Django CreateView does not saving and loading the success url after submit

Tags: python, django, view, create-view

Hello i have been working on django CreateVeiw. As i have add tags and save my post form. But the problem is after i click submit it just reload the page and when i check on my post it didnt add also. Did i miss something out? Can someone answer me?
This is my view of creating post.

```
class PostCreate(CreateView):
    template_name = 'add_post.html'
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        form = form.save(commit=False)
        form.slug = slugify(form.title)
        form.save()
        form.save_m2m()
        return super(PostCreate, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('article-list', args=self.object.id,)
```

Thanks in advance :).

Comment: The form is probably invalid, are you displaying errors from the form in your template?

Comment: @lain sorry am i not clear what you ask but in template form i see no error

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    super().form_valid(form)
    . . .
    form.save()
```

Comment: yes i have already tried. but didnt work also.Thanks for your answer :)